# Efficient algorithms to find out n shortest euclidean length of one point to many other points

Tags: algorithm, math

Trying to find the n shortest length between a lot of points.

Example:

```
A1 = (1.31, 2.22)
B1 = (2.33, 4.88)
C1 = (12,1, 0.11)
.
.
.
.
Z100 = (0.01, 0.05)
target = (1.0, 1.0)
```

The question is, how could I find out the top 10 shortest length of target and another points.Easiest solution is compare them one by one

```
for(size_t i = 0; i != points.size(); ++i){
  priority_queue.push(distance(target, points[i]));
  if(priority_queue.size() >= max_size){
    priority_queue.pop();
  }
}
```

I think complexity is O(n) by this naive solution, is it possible to speed things up?Thanks

Comment: When you calculate the distance you don't need to take the root, you can compare squared distances (write as sum of products, don't use Math.pow or something similar to square, it's often a lot slower), but doesn't improve complexity.

Comment: But you have to use at least O(n) to calculate the distances...or for I/O purpose...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just presented with a list of N points and a single target point, the cost is likely to be O(N) because if this is all you know you will need to examine all of the N points to find the closest 10, and this is cost O(N).

If, for example, you have a list of N points and expect to receive a large number of queries, it may be worth building a data-structure to speed up the search, especially if the number of dimensions in the problem is small (such as 2, in the example you give). Data structures include https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree. If you are satisfied with finding 10 points which are pretty close but not necessarily the 10 closest, then packages such as https://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/ may be useful.